# Create a scalar product based on a norm

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products

It is clear that every *vector space* with a scalar product $\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v}$ has a norm based on this scalar product $\|v\| = \sqrt{\vec{v} \cdot \vec{v}}$.

Now my questions are:

1. In which cases can we define a scalar product out of the norm in a vector space?
2. In the case we know it is possible to define a scalar product out of the norm, is there any method, i.e., formula, to find the scalar product given the norm?

Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity

Comment: @HansLundmark Please, could you write it as an answer. I would momentary accept it as an answer to my second point.

Comment: [Is the parallelogram law the only way to characterise norms induced by inner products?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3445451) (That reminds me: I must finish writing that answer some time!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A norm arises from an inner product iff it satisfies the [parallelogram law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law):
   $$
   |u+v|^2 + |u-v|^2 = 2 |u|^2 + 2 |v|^2
   .
   $$
2. In this case, the inner product can be recovered from the [polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity):
   $$
   u \cdot v = \tfrac14 \bigl( |u+v|^2-|u-v|^2 \bigr)
   .
   $$
   (This is for the case of real vector spaces; for complex vector spaces the formula is a bit more involved.)